# Calculating average elevation from given points layer and DEM

Tags: qgis, point, dem, elevation, population

I am using QGIS 3.18. I have a point layer showing population estimates at the administrative center points and an aster digital elevation map. I'm trying to calculate the average elevation of these points.

Datasets:

1. [Population estimates at administrative unit center points from NASA's socioeconomic data and applications center](https://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/data/set/gpw-v4-admin-unit-center-points-population-estimates-rev11/data-download). (not provided, they need to find it online)
2. Aster Digital Elevation Map (DEM, not provided, they need to find it online)
   Question:

What is the average elevation of Bhutan's and Nepal's administrative center points, respectively?

Comment: Well, what have you tried? Are you aware that points have no area and therefore cannot have an average elevation, but only an elevation at that point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Sample raster values:

> This algorithm creates a new vector layer with the same attributes of
> the input layer and the raster values corresponding on the point
> location.

2. Statistics by categories:

> This algorithm calculates statistics of fields depending on a parent
> class.

[image]